# Want to change the format from datetime to date in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, datepicker

This is how i am trying but the syntax is wrong

```
$scope.A[index].mydatetime | date: 'd-MMM-y' ;
```

but it happened inside :

```
 {{" mydatetime |  date: 'd-MMM-y'"}}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$scope.formattedDate =   $filter('date')($scope.currDate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

[Following formats are supported by angular.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)